# Mapping the :edit command to a certain editor

Tags: emacs, haskell

I've got the Haskell interpreter running in Emacs.

With this I've got the typical Emacs setup of 2 open windows,

- the source file I'm editing
- the Haskell interpreter

Using the command **:edit file** in the interpreter it will open the file I tell it to, but it will open it in Notepad.

Is there a way to map the **:edit** command to use Emacs instead of Notepad.

It looks like the .hs extension is mapped to to ghci on my machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing that the Haskell interpreter will honor the following:

```
:set editor emacsclient
```

and from Emacs do

```
M-x start-server
```

and then when you do

```
:edit file
```

the file will pop up in your Emacs session.  `C-x #` will tell Emacs to tell Haskell to consume the file.

Comment: Is it possible to have it do this for every session of GHCI?

Answer (score 4):

The command you are looking for is `:set editor emacs`.  Using `:edit` will open up a new emacs process.

For me, it's more convenient to simply edit the files in their own buffers and then `:load` and `:reload` them as necessary rather than calling up the editor from within ghci.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just re-assign .hs to emacs, and run ghci from it?

Comment: I'd rather not do that when there is a proper solution already mentioned that will do what I want.